How can I find the name of the list when I get this error "List does not exist error."
When I invoke an action on an Infopath 2010 document I'm getting this error 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: List does not exist.'
I see this error in the server log. The log doesn't tell me what list it can't find.
Any ideas on where to look would be appreciated.
I have looked at the SharePoint logs, SharePoint Designer, Infopath Designer.
The action is attached to an inventory list. It should add the default number of items listed in the list to the requisition form when this action is selected.
